# string descriptor 0 read error: -22 (Wont Bootup)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, usb

I have a Acer Aspire TC-605, my specs are the following:

- Windows 8.1
- Intel Core i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz 3.40GHz
- 12GB Ram
- 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

but I keep getting that error, My PC has Built-In Bluetooth and Wifi but I have no problem with a Live-CD boot on my USB, only after I installed the OS.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsusb && lspci -nnk lGrep -iA2
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04ca:006d Lite-On Technology Corp.
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 18a5:0302 Verbatim, Ltd 32GB Flash Drive
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 04ca:3006 Lite-On Technology Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to install Ubuntu, and did you disable UEFI, Secure Boot etc?

Comment: Is quick boot or fast boot enabled in BIOS

Comment: Not that I know of Jeremy, I will have to check and Wilf, I'm sure I did, I can boot up into the Live CD it just wont work after install.

Comment: I disabled SecureBoot and Enabled Legacy to not use UEFI and I still got this, would it work if I used another PC to install it then I put the hard-drive in my PC?